# Why my chmod do not work even use root user?

Tags: 14.04

I can not add permissions to the files/directory:

```
root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software# chmod +x stacks2.4/
root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software# ll
total 8
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy  344  8月 12 15:01 ./
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy 4096  7月  3 11:58 ../
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy    0  8月 12 14:44 SRA/
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy    0  7月 27 20:45 stacks2.4/
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy 4096  8月 12 14:48 stacks-2.41/
root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software# pwd
/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software


root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software# chmod 777 stacks-2.41/
root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software# ll
total 8
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy  344  8月 12 15:01 ./
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy 4096  7月  3 11:58 ../
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy    0  8月 12 14:44 SRA/
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy    0  7月 27 20:45 stacks2.4/
drwx------ 1 xxy xxy 4096  8月 12 14:48 stacks-2.41/
```

Why my chmod do not work even use root user?

---

**Edit-01**

this is the list:

```
root@xxy-linux:/media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5/Software/stacks-2.41# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   549M  0 part /media/xxy/boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 446.6G  0 part /media/xxy/DA9004FE9004E33D
sdb      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  93.2G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  18.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb6   8:22   0 335.3G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdc2   8:34   0   7.3T  0 part /media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5
sdd      8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdd2   8:50   0   7.3T  0 part /media/xxy/B08813218812E61E
```

---

**Edit-02**

this is the mount:

```
xxy@xxy-linux[xiayun] mount | grep 4ACA                                                 [ 3:44afternoon]
/dev/sdc2 on /media/xxy/4ACA0758CA073FA5 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: What is the file system type?

Comment: see my edit post, its part System Type.

Comment: Nope, some of the details are missing :) Try running `mount | grep 4ACA`

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: "Why my chmod do not work even use root user?" Why do you expect  fuseblk=ntfs to be POSIX compliant?

Comment: I can explain a little further, `ntfs` or `fuseblk` as appears in your config is a Windows compatible filesystem that lacks the required capabilities to support the POSIX/Linux permission scheme, thus the changes you requested cannot be respected by the remote file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work since it's an NTFS file system which doesn't support the POSIX/Linux permission method.